# How can I make a rectangle invisible in tikz to delimit an area an write text on it?

Tags: nodes, text

What I'm trying to do is replicate this image:
[image]

And here is what I got so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4.5,2) -- (4,4) -- node[above]{\textbf{Motivacional} }(0,4) -- (0.5,2) -- (0,0);

\draw[thick] (4.2, 0) -- (8.2, 0) -- (8.7, 2) -- (8.2, 4) -- node[above]{\textbf{Financeiro} }(4.2, 4) -- (4.7 , 2) -- (4.2, 0);

\draw[thick] (8.4, 0) -- (12.4, 0) -- (12.9, 2) -- (12.4, 4) -- node[above, yshift=1em]{\textbf{Informações} } node[above, yshift=-2]{\textbf{Privilegiadas} }(8.4, 4) -- (8.9 , 2) -- (8.4, 0);

\draw[thick] (12.6, 0) -- (16.6, 0) -- (17.1, 2) -- (16.6, 4) -- node[above, yshift=1em]{\textbf{Informações} } node[above, yshift=0.5]{\textbf{Pessoais} }(12.6, 4) -- (13.1 , 2) -- (12.6, 0);

\draw (0.7,0.2) rectangle(3.8,3.8);
\draw (4.9,0.2) rectangle(8,3.8);
\draw (9.1,0.2) rectangle(12.2,3.8);
\draw (13.3,0.2) rectangle(16.4,3.8);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

How can I write the same text of the first image inside those rectangles without actually showing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nodes I would use `signal` shapes:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.14159mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm,
  start chain = going right,
SN/.style = {% Signal Node
             shape=signal, signal from=west, signal pointer angle=120, 
             fill=#1, inner sep=1ex,
             text width=34mm, minimum height=21mm, align=flush left,
             font=\sffamily\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
             on chain},
every label/.style = {text width=24mm, align=center,
                      font=\large\sffamily\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
                      ] 
\node [SN=yellow, label=some text in two lines] {\bfseries
         \hfil 1993\\
         Presenca Corportiva Instucional\\[2ex]
         \normalfont
         Pichacao, Negacao de servicos};
\node [SN=orange!30, label=some text in two lines] {\bfseries
         \hfil 1995\\
         Presenca Corportiva Instucional\\[2ex]
         \normalfont
         Pichacao, Negacao de servicos};
\node [SN=orange, label=some text in two lines] {\bfseries
         \hfil 2000\\
         Presenca Corportiva Instucional\\[2ex]
         \normalfont
         Pichacao, Negacao de servicos};
\node [SN=red, label=some text in two lines] {\bfseries
         \hfil 2010\\
         Presenca Corportiva Instucional\\[2ex]
         \normalfont
         Pichacao, Negacao de servicos};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(in MWE are not correct text, writing them I left to you)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's even better that what I had expected.